# Reading page conten using beautiful soup

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to read page content from the following link:

http://google.com

But, it read the "page source" instead and page source has none of the information displayed on the page.

I have tried the following:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://google.com'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url).read())
```

How do I read the page content. I am using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a request to the ajax api and use `json` to parse the response :

```
import json

url = 'http://esearch.hayscad.com/Search/SearchResults/?keywords=hipoc&filter=&page=6&pageSize=25&skip=125&take=25'
request = urlopen(url)
response = json.loads(request.read())
results = response['ResultsList']
```

Comment: ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded when I use it with my url

Comment: Can you please explain what is difference between your and mine url and how you generated that url ?

Comment: My url calls the ajax api, so i get a json response. You can see what i mean if you open your url in the browser and inspect Network -> HXR . Notice that it makes a call to '/Search/SearchResults/?'

Comment: I need to do more research on your comment .. what is this called? Sorry for lot of questions but this is my first interaction with ajax.

Comment: It's ok, im not very familiar with ajax either. Check this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)

Comment: I found it .. through chrome developer tools. .. appreciate your help